# uglifyjs command line pass max_line_len parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs

I'm using uglifyjs in command-line mode to compress js files. My issue is that i have to Limit the lenght of the lines written when min.js file is generated. 
How/where do i have to specify the

> max_line_len

Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
uglify.minify(input-to-minify, config-obj)
```

the config-obj:

```
config-obj = {
    compress:{
        ...
    },
    ...
    output:{
        max_line_len:1000 // Will limit the length of each line to 1000
    }
    ...
}
```